# Javascript Form Validation With an Array Field Name

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a function that maps validation errors to form fields.

```
export function mapErrorsToForm($form, errorData) {
    $form.find(':input').each(function() {
        var fieldName = $(this).attr('name');
        var $error = $('<div class="invalid-feedback"></div>');
        $error.html(errorData.errors[fieldName]);
        $(this).addClass('is-invalid');
        $(this).after($error);
    });
}
```

errorData is populated from an ajax response, for example:

```
error: function (jqXHR) {
    var errorData = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
    mapErrorsToForm($form, errorData);
}
```

The problem I have is that some field names have arrays, for example password confirmation is written as this:

```
<div class="form-row form-group">
    <div class="col">
        <input class="form-control form-control-lg js-password" type="password" name="plainPassword[first]" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row form-group">
    <div class="col">
        <input class="form-control form-control-lg js-confirm-password" type="password" name="plainPassword[second]" placeholder="Confirm Password">
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I update the mapErrorsToForm function so that it adds validation errors to fields with arrays in the fields name?

Comment: Seems to work correctly when I try it. What's the error you get and how does the errorData look like ?

Comment: This is an example of the error data - {
    "errors": {
        "email": [
            "This email address is already in use"
        ],
        "plainPassword": {
            "first": [
                "The password fields must match."
            ]
        }
    },
    "status": 400,
    "type": "http://localhost:8000/docs/errors#validation_error",
    "title": "There was a validation error"
}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have any (*) character in your field name, maybe you can parse the name like this?

```
var fieldNames = $('input').attr('name').replace(/\[|\]/g, '*').split('*')
// password -> ['password']
// password[first] -> ['password', 'first']
```

If your `errorData.errors` looks like this:

```
{
  password: 'wrong'
}
```

You can get to the error with

```
var error = errorData.errors[fieldNames[0]]
```

. Or if your data looks like this:

```
{
  password: {
    first: 'first wrong',
    second: 'second wrong'
  }
}
```

you can get the error with

```
var key0 = fieldNames[0];
var key1 = fieldNames[1];
var error = errorData.errors[key0][key1]
```

It looks a little bit nicer with es6 rest syntax in a function:

```
const getError = ($elem, error) => {
  const [one, two, ...rest] = $elem.attr('name').replace(/\[|\]/g, '*').split('*');
  if (!two) return error[one];
  return error[one][two]
}
```